# Optimization of Loops and conditionals in Recursive Lua Function

Tags: function, loops, optimization, lua, lua-table

```
The following is the code of my function 


function myfunction ( ... )
  local tbl = table.pack(...)
  for _, v in ipairs(tbl) do
  if type(v) ~= 'number' then
  print('Error: Something different is expected.') 
  return
  elseif v~= math.abs(v) then
   print('Error: Your input needs slight modification.')
   return
  end
  end
 
    if some condition then 
      **recursive call to myfunction**
    else
      some result
    end
  end
```

The function works fine and it gives expected results to me. But the problem as one can observe that function is calling itself in recursive manner. So the first part of the code which I am giving below also gets repeated several times during each recursive call. Obviously I want to check input only once and exit the function if it is incorrect. If input is correct, then it should not be checked every recursive call. So how the code can be optimized for this purpose. Can some value be assigned to global variable and then use it somewhere inside the function (in if else condition) to avoid repetition. But again the check for value will get repeat (though it is less costly compared to the current approach. The problem is to avoid repetition of  the following code (which is part of above code).

```
for _, v in ipairs(tbl) do
  if type(v) ~= 'number' then
  print('Error: Something different is expected.') 
  return
  elseif v~= math.abs(v) then
   print('Error: Your input needs slightly modified')
   return
  end
  end
```

As an example, consider the following function.

```
function factorial(n)
    if (n == 0) then
        return 1
    else
        return n * factorial(n - 1)
    end
end
```

When `factorial(9.3)` is executed it results into stack overflow as no error input check is involved. To handle this the following error mechanism is added.

```
function factorialwithinputcheck(n)
  if type(n) ~= 'number' then
    error('only numbers are expected')
    return
elseif n~= math.floor(n)  or n~=math.abs(n) then
  error('only positive integers are expected')
  return
end
    if (n == 0) then
        return 1
    else
        return n * factorialwithinputcheck(n-1)
    end
end
```

This function gives error and stops execution whenever input is incorrect. The  `factorialwithinputcheck(9.3)` doesn't result into stack overflow. But again the input check is made in every recursive call. How this code for example can be optimised?

Comment: Why not make a function `myfunction_rec` (which does the recursive stuff) and a function `myfunction` which does the input checking and then calls `myfunction_rec` *once*?
(In order to avoid unchecked calls of `myfunction_rec` you could even put this function inside `myfunction`, but I'm not 100% sure if this has other implications regarding performance (don't know whether this way the function has to be instantiated/created multiple times))

Comment: I have edited question with some example. Can the `factorialwithinputcheck` be optimized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being more specific as in my comment, I'd propose something like this:

```lua
function _factorial(n)
    if (n == 0) then
        return 1
    else
        return n * _factorial(n-1)
    end
end

function factorialwithinputcheck(n)
  if type(n) ~= 'number' then
    error('only numbers are expected')
    return
elseif n~= math.floor(n)  or n~=math.abs(n) then
  error('only positive integers are expected')
  return
end
    if (n == 0) then
        return 1
    else
        return n * _factorial(n-1)
    end
end
```

or hiding `_factorial`:

```lua
function factorialwithinputcheck(n)
    local function _factorial(n)
        if (n == 0) then
            return 1
        else
            return n * _factorial(n-1)
        end
    end
  if type(n) ~= 'number' then
    error('only numbers are expected')
    return
elseif n~= math.floor(n)  or n~=math.abs(n) then
  error('only positive integers are expected')
  return
end
    if (n == 0) then
        return 1
    else
        return n * _factorial(n-1)
    end
end
```

but again, I'm not completely sure if this way the `_factorial`  function has to be "created" multiple times (which should have a performance impact as well). But maybe this can be figured out with some benchmarking.

<strike>EDIT: Oh and if you want some input sanitizing: Up to now, you don't check for negative numbers.</strike>

Edit2: And since you ask for general optimization of your factorial function. Yes of course one could convert the recursive procedure into an iterative one (avoiding creating new stack frames that many times).

Using some sort of *accumulator* (`acc`) passing `n*acc` down to the next call, you could alternatively make the function tail recursive, (according to [this pil chapter](https://www.lua.org/pil/6.3.html) (I hope there is no change in that in more frequent lua verions) lua will then handle this for you).
For example:

```lua
local function factorial_rec(n)
    local function _factorial(n)
        if (n == 0) then
            return 1
        else
            return n * _factorial(n-1)
        end
    end
  if type(n) ~= 'number' then
    error('only numbers are expected')
    return
elseif n~= math.floor(n)  or n~=math.abs(n) then
  error('only positive integers are expected')
  return
end
    if (n == 0) then
        return 1
    else
        return n * _factorial(n-1)
    end
end
```

(but to be honest I don't see much of a performance boost with this (`0.000293`s vs `0.000354`s if I loop over `factorial` form 0 to 40, numbers starting with `21!` are already beyond the range for numbers in lua (for my installation), checked only with a very rudimentary benchmark))

Comment: I think negative number check is included in `n~=math.abs(n)`.

Comment: Probably your answer needs some edits.

Comment: Well that's of course right. Sorry for objecting

Comment: Is it possible to add answer using `acc`?

Comment: It prints negative integers for values such as _factorial(21)? Is it possible to add error that it is beyond the scope of Lua to calculate this rather than getting negative results?

Comment: @mathsbeauty: that's because of overflows when using integer arithmetic; if you use double arithmetic, you should first get precision issues and later on +inf. You can force double arithmetic by using `1.0` instead of `1` which will propagate the double number type throughout all multiplications.

Comment: @mathsbeauty: Another option is to just determine (and hardcode) the limit (say, using exact bigint arithmetic by comparing against the double results until it doesn't match). You can find this approach [here](https://github.com/minetest/minetest_docs/blob/master/doc/environment.adoc#mathfactorialx).

Comment: Detecting such overflows isn't that easy I think (sometimes I see `x*y > x` (which still can fail to detect the overflow), for x,y integers, but I definitely haven't that much experience in this field)

Comment: atticus: I'm pretty certain that in this specific case `x*y > x` is probably enough because `y` is *much smaller* than `x` when `x` is near overflow bounds.

Comment: Yes I think so as well. Nevertheless your hardcoding an upper boundary comes with lower performance cost (one check more on the input vs one check on each multiplication) even though finding it could be difficult if one doesn't know on which device the code is being run (not sure if lua integers always have the same size but most probably this already is kinda overengineering)